# DataFrame issue (parenthesis)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

May I ask what's the difference between df.head() and df.head in python's syntax nature? Could I interpret as the former one is for calling a method and the later one is just trying to obtain the DataFrame's attribute, which is the head? I am so confused why sometimes there is a parenthesis at the end but sometimes not... Thank you so much.

Comment: Please don't take down your question after it's been answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand it well, in general parenthesis call class method, and without you call an attribute.

In your exemple you don't have an error, because df.head is bound to NDFrame.head who is a method as well. If df.head was only a method, calling it without parenthesis will raise an AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

We use (parenthesis) for 'Methods' and for 'Attributes' (parenthesis) is not needed. (parenthesis) is use to pass additional parameters into the method.
for example df.head(5) gives you 5 items in the df at the top. You can change that number to 2, 20... without the (parenthesis), you cannot pass that number.

Whereas attributes are just describing the dataframe, for example df.shape,df.dtypes etc, you cannot use (parenthesis) with attributes

In this link [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) you can find the attributes & methods available for a dataframe.